# Django (DRF) fails to POST data to url with similar path

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-urls

In my url conf I have two similar patterns:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', views.chat),  # create chat
    path('chat/message/', views.message),  # create message
]
```

The second path works as expect, however, when I try to POST data to `chat/` I get error 405 and `{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}` error message. The code in the view works, if I modify `chat/` to something more specific like `chat/create/` then everything works fine. However, this is *not* what I want to do. I thought django would match the first URL that matches the request. Why is this happening? It this bug or expected behavior?

Comment: can you post the views? and also how you are posting data

Comment: Views are marked with `api_view(['POST'])` decorators and they are simply returning post data with generate chat/message id (mockups). I use curl to post data to api. In case of `chat/` I send `{"user": 1}` json, and in case of `chat/message/` I send `{"user": 1, "text": "Hello, World!", "chat": 1}`. Views work as expected when urls don't "clash".

Comment: @Liliane just edit your question and add that info there formatted.

Comment: @Liliane just a shortcut. If you don't use regex anchors (unfortunately django 2 removes this feature), always try to put the large path at very first.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue. I created a new `nested_route` decorator that acts a lot like list_route and detail_route. I usually redirect to another viewset to handle the nested path. The issue was that the stream was being read too early (by the parent viewset dispatch), so I needed to ensure that the initialize_request function was only called once for a given request.

Working off of @rsalmaso's comment above, I overrode the `initialize_request` method in the children viewsets with the following.

```
def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(request, Request):
            request = super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return request
```

This works fine, but I think having some sort of attribute for either ignoring the initialize_request function within dispatch or having a global check to only run `initialize_request iff isinstance(request, rest_framework.request.Request) == False`. I'm happy to prepare the PR with tests if that could be acceptable.